# Regex to match an entire word that contains repeated character

Tags: regex, r

All -- need a regex that matches an entire word which contains a character repeated multiple times.  For example, given the sentence "here areee some testtting words" I want to match on "areee" and "testtting".

A pattern like "([a-z])\1{1,}" matches repeated characters, but it returns "eee" and "ttt" as opposed to the entire word containing the repeated characters.  I've experimented with many variations using "\w" for words and "\b" for word borders, but can't seem to make it work...thanks!

Comment: what is the target language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you needed to do was pad it with the necessary gibberish

```
^[a-z]*([a-z])\1{1}[a-z]*$
```

As said in the comments, {1} is never necessary. That makes:

```
^[a-z]*([a-z])\1[a-z]*$
```

View a demo here

https://regex101.com/r/dT6dK8/1

remove the `^` and `$` if you want it to work inline

Comment: AEC -- thanks, also a great solution.  Again, using this in R, so here is the final expression:   gsub("[a-z]*([a-z])\\1{1,}[a-z]*", x, replacement = " ", perl = TRUE)

Comment: Yes but the `{1}` or `{1,}` are useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte true.

And learnedOnPascal, and you can replace [a-z] with \w or any such shorthand you prefer

Comment: @learnedOnPascal - This is the answer that should be used, don't use the lookahead Wektor suggests..

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
\b(?=\w*(\w)\1)\w+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT8nV9/1)

A bit more enhanced version without a lookahead (similar to what [Federico Piazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710099/federico-piazza) suggests in the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012948/regex-to-match-an-entire-word-that-contains-repeated-character/37013006?noredirect=1#comment61578295_37013006)) will look like

```
\b\w*(\w)\1\w*\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT8nV9/2). There is no need setting a quantifier to the backreference `\1` as even two repeated consecutive characters already entitle the word for matching.

Pattern details:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?=\w*(\w)\1)` - a positive lookahead that will require at least 1 repeated word character (the `\w*` will match 0+ word characters, `(\w)` will match and capture into Group 1 a word character and `\1` will match the same character captured into Group 1) in the word that will be matched with...
- `\w+` - 1+ word characters
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

R code demo for *word with repeated consecutive letters extraction*:

```
> library(stringr)
> text = "here areee some testtting words"
> str_extract_all(text, "\\b(?=\\w*(\\w)\\1)\\w+\\b")
[[1]]
[1] "areee"     "testtting"
```

And a demo for these words *removing*:

```
> gsub("\\s*\\b(?=\\w*(\\w)\\1)\\w+\\b", text, replacement = " ", perl = TRUE)
[1] "here  some  words"
```

See the `\\s*` added at the start of the pattern to also trim the whitespaces (if any) before the word to remove. If you need to also get rid of the inital whitespace that appears after removing the first word, use `trimws()`.

**NOTE**: If you plan to only check for repeated *letters*,  use `\b(?=\w*([a-zA-Z])\1)\w+\b`

Comment: SUCCESS...thank you Wiktor Stribiżew.   I'm using this in R so the final expression looks like this:    gsub("\\b(?=\\w*(\\w)\\1)\\w+\\b", x, replacement = " ", perl = TRUE)

Comment: Ok, I will add an R demo then. `str_extract_all` from *stringr* will do.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza: I might also have suggested this enhancement, but my wife was grumbling too hard, I had to give her the computer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew lol, used to happen. Also `\w*(\w)\1+\w*` mades the trick too. Know you know, but just mentioning for OP